# Change html attribute based on list data in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

In Ember, we are using `{{each}}` to loop through a list of items.

We would like to change an attribute based on whether a data item contains the text `"COMPLETE"` or not.

If the data `item = "COMPLETE"` then change the div style, otherwise don't.

Answer (score 0):

In Application.js, add a Handlebar with a name, which accepts a value.

This will return the value wrapped in a , and depending on the content, it will return either a plain, or styles span element.

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('styled_status', function(value) {
    var escaped = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(value);
    if(escaped == "COMPLETE_SUCCESS") {
    return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString('<span>' + escaped + '</span>');
  }
    return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString('<span class="label label-danger">' + escaped + '</span>');
});
```

The Handlebar can be called from the html page as follows;

```
<p>{{styled_status listelement.jobStatus}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to use [`itemController`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html#property_itemController) property of the controller and bind that attribute to a property.

```
{{#each post in controller}}
  <li {{bind-attr class="post.isComplete:complete"}}>{{post.title}} ({{post.titleLength}} characters)</li>
{{/each}}


App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'post'
});

App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  // the `title` property will be proxied to the underlying post.
  titleLength: function() {
    return this.get('title').length;
  }.property('title'),
  isComplete : function(){
    return Ember.isEqual(this.get('state'), 'COMPLETE');
  }.property('state')
});
```

Hope, this helps